# In Dojo 1.7+, FilteringSelect appear to no longer workwith ItemFileReadStore

Tags: dojo

I am upgrading an application from dojo 1.5 to 1.7. This application has several FilteringSelects that are backed by ItemFileReadStores. E.g.,

```
  this.docTypeSel = this.adopt(dijit.form.FilteringSelect, {
       name: "docType",
       autoComplete: true
  }, document.createElement("select"));
  this.docTypeSel.placeAt(this.formNode);
  var url = dojo.moduleUrl("imed", "DocumentTypes.txt");
  this.documentTypeStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ url: url, urlPreventCache: "true" });
  this.docTypeSel.store = this.documentTypeStore;
```

In 1.7, calls to `this.docTypeSel.set('value',foo)` fail as they try to call `this.store.get(value)`. My understanding is that this is the new dojo/store API. Is there some sort of adapter between the old dojo.data API's and the new dojo/store API? If not, what is the recommended replacement for ItemFileReadStore. dojo/store/Memory seems close, but it does not appear to have a way pull the data from an url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at using the [dojo/store/DataStore](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/store/DataStore.html#dojo-store-datastore)?  I haven't used it personally but it appears to be what you want to use since the `dijit/form/FilteringSelect` is looks for stores using the `dojo/store` API.

On the other hand the dijit/form/Select expects a `dojo/data` implementation.  If you had a `dojo/store` implementation you wanted to use with `dijit/form/Select` you would use [dojo/data/ObjectStore](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/data/ObjectStore.html#dojo-data-objectstore).